# Robocopy script copied permissions/subfolders everything but NOT shares

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, file-sharing, robocopy, dfs-r

I ran this command on my new server:

```
ROBOCOPY "\\oldserver\e$\folder" "e:\folder\" /COPYALL /SEC /MIR /LOG:logs.txt
```

It copies all permission and mirrored my folder but later I realized that shares are missing.

I want to totally sync this new server's folder with the old one. Keep in mind that the folder is couple hundred GBs so I cannot copy it again. So, how can I only copy all the shares of every subfolder withing e:\folder ??

Suggest me if I make a DFS Replication group, will the folder shares be synced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robocopy can copy the files, folders, permissions, etc. but not the Share information. You'll need to export the Shares from the registry on the source server and import them into the registry on the destination server.